# navigation bake for prefabs this is possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a pool of objects, this object are some prefabs, but I can not find the way to do it `navigation -> bake` work, there is some way to apply the`bake` to prefabs, or plicate it at run time.

Currently the alternative I am using is to apply the `bake` to an object in the unity editor and move it where the new part of the pool appears, In the same position, to be able to use the navmesh.

I would like to know if the comment is possible, or if not, the last would be a good alternative, or which would be a good alternative?

I'm sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand me

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity's advanced features, which is the "NavMeshComponents", you can bake a prefab into a single navmesh and use navmesh link to connect between those prefabs.

There's a github demo about this you can check. I've used that and it works fine.
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents

Comment: We try to avoid links as answers on SO. Links are not permanent. A link should be an extension rather than the meat of the explanation. Try editing your answer to include a summary.